# How to suppress uncaught exceptions in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, exception

Exceptions can be suppressed in Chrome and Firefox but none of the approaches work in IE

```
window.addEventListener("error", function errorHandler(event) {
    console.log("exception should be suppressed and not shown in the console");
    event.preventDefault();
});

throw "suppress me";
```

and

```
window.onerror = function errorHandler() {
    console.log("exception should be suppressed and not shown in the console");
    return true;
};

throw "suppress me";
```

You can play with them

https://jsfiddle.net/9uj4xm3g/4/

https://jsfiddle.net/gv0pvy3b/3/

Any ideas?

**UPD:**

I forgot to clarify what I mean by ***suppressing***. I would like to be able to hide **SCRIPT5022** message completely by marking an error as ***handled***.

[image: Internet Explorer doesn't allow to suppress uncaught exceptions in console]

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197053.aspx

> To suppress the default Windows Internet Explorer error message for
>   the window event, set the returnValue property of the event object to
>   true or simply return true in Microsoft JScript.

But as you see this doesn't help with errors logged to the console

Comment: IE probably has it's own method called gavin or something ... I gave up coding for IE years ago, IE users just get derogatory messages on my sites - I meant to add, have you tried searching msdn for any clues?

Comment: @JaromandaX I've updated my question to point to the MSDN article which seems to be relevant but not helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you're throwing the exception.

You should be doing the following:

```
throw new Error("my error");
```

Here's a reference: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/10/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors-part-2/

Comment: This doesn't make any difference to the original problem. See https://jsfiddle.net/9uj4xm3g/5/ and https://jsfiddle.net/gv0pvy3b/4/ . I am also updating the question to clarify the problem

Comment: And also you suggestion is good for our own code but I would like to be able to handle 3rd party libs that might throw Errors as plain strings